# How to change default page slug?

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, slug, s3-rewrite-rules

I have a CPT called jobs and a page named Job Apply. I am trying to achieve something like below url:

```
http://example.com/job-slug/apply
```

Where, **job-slug** can be any job. i.e Programmer, Developer etc..

On clicking job's apply button, it should open an apply page which consists a simple form, but url should be as mentioned above.

I am trying to achieve it by using add_rewrite_rule(), but after trying too much, it is still redirecting me on the below url:

```
http://example.com/apply
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Vishal, are you trying to achieve this in .htaccess rewriting rules? If you could confirm on this one I could try to help here, cheers.